# How to display PowerShell results horizontally instead of vertically?

Tags: windows, powershell, powercli

For example, you specified a variable as shown below.

```
$data1 = get-psdrive | where-object {$_.name -like 'c'} | select -expandproperty used

$data2 = get-psdrive | where-object {$_.name -like 'c'} | select -expandproperty free

echo $data1,data2
```

The output is vertical.

```
$data1

$data2
```

I used `write-host -nonewline` to display output horizontally, but the command does not export to txt

```
write-host $data1 -nonewline; write-host $data2 -nonewline >> c:\test.txt
```

How can I display horizontally and export in txt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about converting to json (or csv)?  Note that ">>" can mix encodings, but add-content doesn't.

```
get-psdrive c | select used, free | ConvertTo-Json -Compress | 
  add-content test.txt
get-content test.txt

{"Used":217365741568,"Free":21004943360}
```

Or just join them.  Too bad select -expand doesn't work with multiple properties.

```
psdrive c | % { ($_.used,$_.free) -join ',' }

217382371328,20988313600
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `Write-Host` for this. Even if you change to `Write-Host -NoNewLine` it'll still never work because [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host?view=powershell-7.1) is intended for **directly writing into the screen** and **can't be redirected** unless you use PowerShell 5+ and redirect the stream number 6 (Information stream)

```
Write-Host -NoNewLine $data1,$data2 6>output.txt
```

in which case it doesn't print out to string of course. In short `Write-Host` in PowerShell 5+ doesn't write to stdout but the *Information stream*

The **real solution** to writing to screen with the ability to redirect to file or pipe to another command is to use [`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output?view=powershell-7.1) (which `echo` is an alias to), and simply use a single string to write to a single line

```
Write-Output "$data1,$data2"
echo "$data1,$data2"
echo ($data1 + "," + $data2)
```

See [Write-Host Considered Harmful](https://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/) for more details

Comment: what's wrong with this? Someone seems to not understand powershell

Answer (score -2):

Use a double quote string with your variables: `Write-Host “$data1,$data2”`

Read more https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.1

Comment: This isn't a here string, just a normal interpolated string

Comment: this still won't work. `write-host $data2 -nonewline >> c:\test.txt` will never write to file but still print to screen. And your "quotes" are smart quotes `“”` instead of the normal quote `""` so it also doesn't work